# trying to change or renew client Id and client secret on the run in java code

Tags: java, multithreading

Currently I am trying to use an app where initially it registers and then works but after a period of time it's limit is exhausted.
I am trying to change the client id and client secret on the run without stopping the API. But it is not changing . Is there any reason for that?
Is there any work around for this how I can do that without completely stopping the same.
Adding the code snippet.
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
boolean flag = true;
clientKeyList.add(Client_Id_1);
keyMap.put(Client_Id_1, Client_Secret_1);
clientKeyList.add(Client_Id_2);
keyMap.put(Client_Id_2, Client_Secret_2);
clientKeyList.add(Client_Id_3);
keyMap.put(Client_Id_3, Client_Secret_3);

for(int i =0;i < clientKeyList.size();i++  ){

    flag=true;
    Translate.setClientId(clientKeyList.get(i));
    Translate.setClientSecret(keyMap.get(clientKeyList.get(i)));
    while(flag){

        logger.info("the untranslated text is :- " + text);
        String translatedText = Translate.execute(text , Language.FRENCH, Language.ENGLISH);
        if(translatedText.contains("ApiException:"))
        {
            System.out.println(translatedText);
            flag=false;
        }
        logger.info("the translated text is :- " + translatedText);

    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code and add some more context.

Comment: what is Translate.setClientId() doing? is it setting value in some POJO or its setting any system property or any static variable?

Comment: Translate.setClientId() is setting up the client Id in the built in POJO for Translate class. The client ID is obtained after we register for an app.